# UWP How to notify of Process's termination?

Tags: c#, uwp, diagnostics

For UWP, I am looking for something similar to .NET `System.Diagnostics.Process` capability for notifying about Process's termination like:

```
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.Exited += Process_Exited;

...

private static void Process_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var process = (Process)sender;
    // Do some stuff
}
```

At the moment, I'm able to work out `Windows.System.Diagnostics.ProcessDiagnosticInfo` object which represent a 'the Process' I need. The problem is, that `Windows.System.Diagnostics.ProcessDiagnosticInfo` type doesn't provide mechanism (event, etc) which could tell me 'Hey, this process has been ended'.

Does any UWP's API support it ?

Comment: Have you tried `CoreApplication.Exiting` ?

Comment: Well, the thing it, that 'the Process' I want to monitor is not a process of my UWP app. It is external process. For instance a process of Notepad which opens specific txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems no UWP API is available for this so far. `ProcessDiagnosticInfo` provides basic info about a process and there doesn't seem to be any way to further manipulate it (e.g. wire up events). Furthermore, even though UWP now supports .NET Standard, the classes related to `System.Diagnostics.Process` mostly throw `PlatformNotSupported` exception, presumably for security reasons.

The only option I can see now is to query the list of running processes repeatedly and check if the process you are watching is still listed or not. Of course, is not the best solution, as you won't get an immediate notification, so if you want faster feedback, you must execute the check more often.